# How can I change the font color and size of one word in CSS animation?

Tags: html, css

I am very new to CSS. I am trying to get one word in my sentence to change font size and color after my animation. I tried adding a span class to the word like so:

```
<h2>I'm <span style = "font-size: 20px; color: red">available</span> for work</h2></span>
```

And then adding a class to my CSS to see if it would work there:

```
.my-class {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

But neither of these seems to have any effect. How can I adjust the size and color of just one word with CSS?

```css
/* Global Variables */

 :root {
  --main-bg-color: #DDD0C8;
  --secondary-bg-color: #323232;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: --main-font-size;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: beige;
}


/*---CONTACT SECTION---*/

.contact-container {
  background-color: darkgray;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-text h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contact-text p {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: var(--main-font-size);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.shine_animation {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #fff, #000);
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  animation: shine 5s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    background-position-x: -500%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 500%;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Head -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cedarville+Cursive&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Contact Section -->
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-text" , id="contact">
      <h2>I'm <span style = "font-size: 20px; color: red">available</span> for work</h2>
      </span>
      <span><p>Get in touch with me today.</p></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't looks like it changed the font size of the span because the `h2` also have `font-size: 20px;`. Can you try to change the span font size to `30px`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're there, you just need to add the `.shine_animation` class to your span. Then you should be good to go.

I'll note, if these are the colors it's not very accessible, but you can continue to work on that.

If you also want the text to be bigger, you'd just need to add the `font-size` to the `.shine_animation` class. You'll also need to remove the `style` tag that currently exists on the span.

*I edited this first example to do what was asked for in the comments. First, the animation runs on the `h2` then another animation runs on the work "available". The trick to the second animation is that you need to set the `animation-delay` to be the same length of the first animation. Additionally, in the first animation you set the text fill color to transparent (this property can't be animated). Part of the reason you weren't seeing the change is because all of the `h2` had transparent text for the animation to show through it.
Again, I would note that these colors aren't accessible.*

```css
/* Global Variables */

 :root {
  --main-bg-color: #DDD0C8;
  --secondary-bg-color: #323232;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: --main-font-size;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: beige;
}


/*---CONTACT SECTION---*/

.contact-container {
  background-color: darkgray;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-text h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contact-text p {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: var(--main-font-size);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.shine_animation {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #fff, #000);
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  animation: shine 5s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    background-position-x: -500%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 500%;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
}

.grow {
  animation: grow 2s forwards 5s;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    font-size: 20px;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 40px;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Head -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cedarville+Cursive&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Contact Section -->
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-text" id="contact">
      <h2 class="shine_animation">I'm <span class="grow">available</span> for work</h2>
      </span>
      <span><p>Get in touch with me today.</p></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I added the `.shine_animation` class to the span as you suggested, but now it only works on the word "available" (no color change) and the animation is different?

Comment: What animation are you trying to accomplish? Just change the font-size and color?

Comment: everything that is in the current `.shine_animation` class should apply to the header `h2` and parapgraph `p`. After this, I want to change the font size and color of the word "available".

Comment: I just edited, to show you changing the size and color of the word "available" on hover. To be clear, you would like the animation to run over the whole `h2`, and after the animation, you want to animate the color and size of the word "available"?

Comment: ok thank you yes I see it changing. Yes, I would like the animation to run over the whole `h2` (and `p`), and after that, I want to animate the color and size of "available".

Comment: Just edited again. Check the first Snippet/Demo in the answer. You'll need to do a little bit around the colors to animate them how you'd like, but that should be working now.

Comment: yes this does what I am trying to achieve. Accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1 {
  animation-name: example-animate;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
@keyframes example-animate {
  from {
    color: red;
    font-size:16px;
  }
  to {
    color: yellow;
    font-size:50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Animation Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Font Color And Size Change With Animation.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

To change the font color and size of one word in CSS animation:

I added the `-webkit-text-fill-color` property to the `.font-color-size` class, which sets the text fill color explicitly to red. This should now change the font size and color of the word "available" to 20px and red, respectively.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cedarville+Cursive&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">

  <style>
    /* Global Variables */
    :root {
        --main-bg-color: #DDD0C8;
        --secondary-bg-color: #323232;    
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    html {
      font-size: --main-font-size;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: beige;
    }

    /*---CONTACT SECTION---*/
    .contact-container {
      background-color: darkgray;
      padding-top: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .contact-text h2 {
      font-weight: 700;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;   
    }

    .contact-text p {
      font-weight: 700;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: var(--main-font-size);
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
    }

    .shine_animation {
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #fff, #000);
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 80%;
      animation: shine 5s linear infinite; 
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      position: relative;
    }

    @keyframes shine {
      0% {
        background-position-x: -500%;
      }
      100% {
        background-position-x: 500%;
        background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
      }
    }

    /* Custom class to change font size and color */
    .font-color-size {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: red;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: red; /* Set the text fill color explicitly */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Contact Section -->
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-text" id="contact">
      <h2>I'm <span class="shine_animation">available</span> for work</h2>
      <span><p>Get in touch with me today.</p></span>  
    </div> 
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not change the font size or color.